# Argument OutofRange Exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, string, exception

My code flips a word, and it works but shows this error:

> Argument OutofRange Exception was unhandled

The error is being shown for the line `strFlippedWord = strUserWord.Sub...`

```
string strUserWord;
string strFlippedWord;
int intWordLength;

System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word to flip: ");
strUserWord = System.Console.ReadLine();
intWordLength = strUserWord.Length;
while (intWordLength != -1)
{

    strFlippedWord = strUserWord.Substring(intWordLength - 1, 1); 
    System.Console.Write(strFlippedWord);
    intWordLength -= 1;
}

System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: are you trying to reverse the string i.e. "abc" -> "cba" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the loop too long.

```
while (intWordLength > 0)
```

Also, you could eliminate the loop altogether and use a bit of LINQ:

```
Console.WriteLine(strUserWord.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly after I fixed the loop condition. Thanks for all the additional answers too..:D

Answer (score 0):

When `intWordLength` is 0, you pass -1 as the first parameter to String.Substring, which is an invalid argument. Change your `while` condition to `while( intWordLength > 0 )`.

Comment: I missed when wordlength is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
while (intWordLength != -1)
{
    if (intWordLength == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    strFlippedWord = strUserWord.Substring(intWordLength - 1, 1);
    System.Console.Write(strFlippedWord);
    intWordLength -= 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are starting at the last char in the string and traveling foward 1 element

try :

```
strFlippedWord = strUserWord.Substring(intWordLength - 1, 0);
```

if you are trying to Reverse the string

```
strFlippedWord = new string(strUserWord.Reverse().ToArray());
```

*EDIT*

as babak has stated about intwordlength:

the while statement could be

```
while(!(intwordlength < 1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

When intWordLength is 0, Substring throws the exception you see.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

In this circumstance you are passing -1, which is not legal.